# How to convert float value to integer in php?

Tags: php, floating-point, int

I want to convert float value (Eg:1.0000124668092E+14) to Integer in php,what is the best method for this in php.output should be "100001246680920"

Answer (score 79):

What do you mean by converting?

- casting*: `(int) $float` or `intval($float)`
- truncating: `floor($float)` (down) or `ceil($float)` (up)
- rounding: `round($float)` - has additional [modes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), see `PHP_ROUND_HALF_...` constants

*******: casting has some chance, that float values cannot be represented in int (too big, or too small), f.ex. in your case.

> [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php): The largest integer supported in this build of PHP. Usually int(2147483647).

But, you could use the [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php), or the [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extensions for handling these large numbers. (Both are boundled, you only need to enable these extensions)

Comment: so can i get integer representation as string eg:(string)"100001246680920"

Comment: with rounding or truncating, you get a float. with these extensions, you can handle it like strings.

Comment: Note that `floor()` and `ceil()` will still return as type `float`, as, according to the documentation, "the value range of float is usually bigger than that of integer".

Answer (score 44):

I just want to **WARN** you about:

```
>>> (int) (290.15 * 100);
=> 29014
>>> (int) round((290.15 * 100), 0);
=> 29015
```

Comment: after 3 days of dancing with the torch you give us some light, do you know why so simple math fail in PHP?

Comment: Not really, it seems that some numbers are hidden in memory

Comment: If you try to do var_dump(290.15*100) you can see that the internal representation is float(29014.999999999996). So applying (int) takes the integer part, that is 29014, while using round() takes the closer integer value.

Answer (score 17):

Use `round()`

```
$float_val = 4.5;

echo round($float_val);
```

You can also set param for precision and rounding mode, for [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Update (According to your updated question):

```
$float_val = 1.0000124668092E+14;
printf('%.0f', $float_val / 1E+14); //Output Rounds Of To 1000012466809201
```

Comment: out put getting 1,not 100001246680920

Comment: @sajith You want your float to round off, so exponential value will make it 201 and not 20

Comment: @sajith Do you mean the last digit?

Comment: @sajith Oh god, I am not understanding how this won't work, It works completely for me

Comment: i clearly mentioned integer,but i am not getting the out put only shows 1 as o/p

Comment: @sajith You are doing it wrong than, just copy paste both lines, use it, don't use echo and see the result

Comment: <?php
$float_val = 1.0000124668092E+14;
printf('%.0f', $float_val / 1E+14); //Output Rounds Of To 1000012466809201
?> o/p:1

Comment: i need a function to convert this float value to integer representation example  i/p will be 1.0000124668092E+14 and it give o/p as 100001246680920

Comment: Doesn't answer to the OP question, round returns a float, he wants an integer. Or types don't matter anymore ?

Answer (score 8):

There is always intval() - Not sure if this is what you were looking for...

example: -

```
$floatValue = 4.5;
echo intval($floatValue);    // Returns 4
```

It won't round off the value to an integer, but will strip out the decimal and trailing digits, and return the integer before the decimal.

Here is some documentation for this: - 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: Hi, I made the changes. Would this be sufficient?

Answer (score 8):

**Try this**

```
<?php
$float_val = 1.0000124668092E+14;
 echo intval($float_val);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `round`, `floor` or `ceil` methods to round it to the closest integer, along with `intval()` which is limited.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php