# How to remain number as string in PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have created services that request FB for real-time updates. The result that return by Facebook is in JSON type. Its like this:

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"248874468652581","time":1428654497,"changes":[{"field":"feed","value":{"item":"comment","verb":"add","comment_id":"248878481985513_367520770121283","parent_id":"248874468652581_248878498652178","sender_id":1490984774509544,"created_time":1428654497,"sender_name":"Orlig Anbiz","message":"helo"}}]}]}
```

Then i want to keep all data in this JSON to store in database. My problem is at

```
"sender_id":1490984774509544,
```

Which is the sender id (number without double qoutes). Then when I put this sender_id in var, it is automatically convert it into float. My php code:

```
$sender_id = strval($json_array['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['sender_id']);
echo nl2br("The Sender ID = $sender_id \n");
```

My result for sender_id will become like this:

```
The Sender ID = 1.4909847745095E+15
```

I dont want that sender ID change to float but keep as string which is supposed to display like this:

```
The Sender ID = 1490984774509544
```

Please Help. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Try $sender_id = settype($json_array['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['sender_id'],"string");

Comment: maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621792/convert-a-big-integer-to-a-full-string-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456615/how-to-convert-float-value-to-integer-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456615/how-to-convert-float-value-to-integer-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var =  json_decode('{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"248874468652581","time":1428654497,"changes":[{"field":"feed","value":{"item":"comment","verb":"add","comment_id":"248878481985513_367520770121283","parent_id":"248874468652581_248878498652178","sender_id":1490984774509544,"created_time":1428654497,"sender_name":"Orlig Anbiz","message":"helo"}}]}]}',true,512,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
    var_dump((($var['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['sender_id'])));
```

result:

```
string '1490984774509544' (length=16)
```

Comment: you save my day bro! Thank You :). actually after put `true,512,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` after JSON i no need to put `var_dump` anymore bcoz its keep remain as string

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the database to interpret your value as a number, don't save it as a number.

You need to store it as a non numerical string datatype, like `varchar` or if its too long then `text` fits your bill.

In this case,
You seem to be using `float` datatype for the column, just login to phpmyadmin, and change the data type of that column to one of the above mentioned type.

**Update:-**

You can use "type casting" to change the variable datatype.
In your code ...

```
$sender_id =  (string) $json_array['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['sender_id'];
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick response. No, before go into database its already change to float when through this line: `$sender_id = strval($json_array['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['sender_id']);` and my datatype column in db is nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of `json_decode` as stated in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  is:

> options: Bitmask of JSON decode options. Currently only JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING is supported (**default is to cast large integers as floats**)

So you need to add `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` as an `$option` param:

`json_decode ( $json, $assoc = true, $depth = 512, $options = JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING )`

This way you will preserve `json_decode` from casting large integers to floats.

So in your case you should not change `$json_array` but rather change the way you get to it. You should do something like this:

```
$json_array = json_decode($jsonYouGotFromFacebook, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

And your `$json_array` should be just fine.

Hope this helps!